# dynamic reconfigure with a variable-length list of parameters

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I just went over the tutorials of [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile). It says that for the type of a parameter the following options are available:

```
type - defines the type of value stored, and can be any of int_t, double_t, str_t, or bool_t
```

Now, I'd like to have a dynamic parameter which is a list of doubles. I'd like to further dynamically reconfigure the length of that list. Is this possible?

The tutorial says no and I found no related answer/question here. Still, I think this to be a valuable feature and am wondering whether somebody else already thought about it.

Cheers,
Georg.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101086/dynamic-reconfigure-with-a-variable-length-list-of-parameters/) by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2013-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I was wondering the same thing and posted this question:

http://answers.ros.org/question/138231/dynamic-reconfigure-can-i-set-an-array-of-values/

I don't think it's possible. I opted for a service with a custom message type.

---

Originally posted by [trianta2](https://answers.ros.org/users/8336/trianta2/) with karma: 293 on 2014-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on 2014-10-16**:
Thanks for your suggestion. I also think this is not possible. So, I'm closing this question. :)